# How to configure selenoid to use a specific version of selenoid/video-recorder to be used to record session

Tags: selenoid

is there any way to mention which version of selenoid/video-recorder should be used while selenoid is started? either in docker-compose.yml or command line?

I get following error, due to the docker pull limit issue, so I need to mention the specific version i have pulled earlier.

2021/04/08 10:35:59 [909] [5.64s] [SESSION_FAILED] [test] [x.x.x.x] [chrome-89.0] [x.x.x.x:4444] [-] [6] **[start video container: create video container: Error response from daemon: No such image: selenoid/video-recorder:latest-release]**

Following is my docker compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
 selenoid:
   network_mode: bridge
   image: aerokube/selenoid:1.10.1
   volumes:
     - "/opt/selenoid:/etc/selenoid"
     - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
     - "/opt/selenoid/video:/opt/selenoid/video"
   environment:
     - OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=/opt/selenium/video
     - TZ=America/Montreal
     - limit=10
   command: ["-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json", "-video-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/video"]
   ports:
     - "4444:4444"
 selenoid-ui:
   image: "aerokube/selenoid-ui"
   network_mode: bridge
   links:
     - selenoid
   ports:
     - "8080:8080"
   command: ["--selenoid-uri", "http://selenoid:4444"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Respective image can be specified with `-video-recorder-image` flag in in `command` section. All available flags are listed here: https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_selenoid_cli_flags